# App crashes when I use image picker on iOS Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to pick the image, app immediately crashes and stop working. On simulator it just shows in console "lost connection to device" and crashes. in real device my app just stops working. I added all the requirement parameters to info plist, and search for the solution. But nothing works for me. I also use the last version of image_picker and flutter.
My info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
        <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
        <string>$(MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)</string>
        <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_COPYRIGHT)</string>
        <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
        <string>MainMenu</string>
        <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>NSApplication</string>
        <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Access to take a photo by camera</string>
        <string>Access to pick a photo</string>
        <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Access to pick a photo</string>
        <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Access to pick a photo</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

my image picker service:

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class ImageService {
  static Future pickImage() async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    final image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  
    return image;
  }
}
```

Thats  where I  use it:

```
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () async {
          final image = await ImageService.pickImage();
          ctrl.imagesAddedToVisa.add(image);
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 80,
          width: 150,
          child: DottedBorder(
              color: AppColors.mainTint,
              radius: const Radius.circular(16),
              dashPattern: const [5, 16],
              strokeWidth: 3,
              strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.fileCirclePlus,
                      color: AppColors.mainColor,
                      size: 35,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                        'add_passport_photo'.tr,
                        maxLines: 2,
                        softWrap: true,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I found solution. I just added manually         <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 this one to my Xcode project

Answer (score 1):

Your Info.plist used has an error:

```xml
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access to take a photo by camera</string>
<string>Access to pick a photo</string>
```

You should choose one of the strings and remove the other:

```xml
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access to take a photo by camera</string>
```

You shouldn't be able to compile the app with that error, make sure to fix it and restart the app.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed it and fixed. But it didn't fix my issue anyway